# Is there a way to simplify initializing Linq new object initialization?

Tags: c#, linq

I find that I am repeating a lot of new object initialization code in Linq queries, for example when creating different overloaded methods that use the same query structure.

```
var result = ItemResponses
    .GroupBy(ir => ir.ItemID)
    .Select(
        grouped => new 
        {
            ItemID = grouped.Key,
            Average = (double)grouped.Average(g => g.OptionValue),
            ...etc. lots of properties, similar structure across lots of methods...
            ...Would really love to be able to write this code once somewhere...
        }
    );
```

At first I thought using constructors might be one way of doing it, something along these lines:

```
var result = ItemResponses
    .GroupBy(ir => ir.ItemID)
    .Select(grouped => new TestClass(grouped)   //or anonymous type
    );

public class TestClass
{
    public int ItemID { get; set; }
    public double Average { get; set; }

    public TestClass() {}

    public TestClass(IGrouping<int, ItemRespons> values)
    {
        ItemID = values.Key;
        Average = values.Average(g => g.OptionValue);
    }   
}
```

But I see that Linq (to Entities at least) only allows parameterless constructors and initializers. So this approach doesn't seem to work.

Is there another way I can achieve simplifying this type of repetive code, and only having it in one place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `delegate`:

```
Func<IQueryable<ItemResponse>,IEnumerable<TestClass>> SelectResult = q => 
q.GroupBy(ir => ir.ItemID)
 .Select(
     grouped => new TestClass
     {
         ItemID = grouped.Key,
         Average = (double)grouped.Average(g => g.OptionValue),
         ...
     });
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
var result = SelectResult(ctx.ItemResponse);
```

It's even better to make it a extension method of course:

```
public static class Extensions
{
   public static IEnumerable<TestClass> SelectResult(this IQueryable<ItemResponse> q)
   {
      return q.GroupBy(ir => ...)
   }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
var result = ctx.ItemResponses.SelectResult();
```

Comment: Very useful - I just tried implementing an extension approach, and that seems to work well so far.

Comment: @PropositionJoe The `IEnumerable<T>` interface is built around extension methods, it's always a good idea to write them for linq queries you reuse a lot

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible for anonymous type projections because there is no way to define a typed result, except some non generic type like `dynamic`, `object` or `IQueryable`, but then you'll have problem consuming it.

However it is possible to reuse projections to a custom types (like your sample `TestClass`). But instead of constructor, you have to put the code in a expression returning method.

For instance, instead of this

```
public TestClass(IGrouping<int, ItemResponse> values)
{
    ItemID = values.Key;
    Average = values.Average(g => g.OptionValue);
    // ...etc. lots of properties
}
```

you could use something like this

```
static Expression<Func<IGrouping<int, ItemResponse>, TestClass>> ToTestClass()
{
    return values => new TestClass
    {
        ItemID = values.Key,
        Average = values.Average(g => g.OptionValue)
        // ...etc. lots of properties
    };
}
```

and the sample query would be

```
var result = ItemResponses
    .GroupBy(ir => ir.ItemID)
    .Select(ToTestClass());
```